# Global configuration and class management

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want to store parameters and handles of objects in a single place (C++) so that every other object in this project can get these information and they only need to be changed in one place. For example I have some strings and a (single!) object which handles an external device. Now different objects all over the project should be able to handle the external device by using the same instance of the controlling object.

What is the best way to implement this? Is there a pattern? Should I have one static class which initializes all these objects and variables and gives a reference of it to objects when asked for? Or should I hand over the reference to these objects all the time - what I do at the moment and really don't like.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that Singleton pattern is what you are looking for, but it's considered as anti-pattern in some situations

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/2493903/undercover already said, singleton is what you need.

Example:

```
class Foobar
{
public:

    static Foobar & singleton()
    {
        static Foobar foo;
        return foo;
    }

private:
    Foobar();
    Foobar( const Foobar & ); // don't implement
    Foobar & operator=( const Foobar & ); // don't implement
};
```

Comment: Beware however that the "naive" implementation of the Singleton pattern is in general not thread-safe.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider Singleton, like it was said, but some supplement should be added IMO.

Using Singleton should be well defined in design to avoid mess in project, otherwise it becomes global variable with its almost all disadvantages(almost, because it's easier to make Singleton thread-safe ;))

Personally I prefer dependency injection, because when someone have to do more work than

```
Foo::getInstance().doSomething();
```

then he will more likely consider if he really needs to use this class here.